# Cucumber, confirm browser dialog which shows when page starts to refresh

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

When one scenario is done, the page refreshes (in the website there is a javascript modal implemented before refreshing the page which asks the user "Are you sure you want to leave the page?"). I need to confirm that modal. But when I create the step for that, I always get this error:

```
Then User clicks "Leave this page" button in the popup at online reg form
      no alert open
        (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.114)
```

and the code

```
And(/^User clicks "([^"]*)" button in the popup at online reg form$/) do |button|
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new
  alert = wait.until { page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert }
  alert.accept
end
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the confirm dialogue method in javascript to always return true

```
page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
```

use this line before the line of code that triggers the dialogue to popup and it will always accept it no more steps needed :)